# C++ (Error C4275) How to create a interface class in a static library that will be used across multiple dll's with export defines

Tags: c++, interface

I have a static library that houses some purely virtual interfaces that is shared with most of my DLL's.

```
class IBase
{
public:
    //Cannot be virtual or child destructors will not be called
    virtual ~IBase() {} //<- This guy causes my issues
 
    virtual void someFunction() = 0;
}
```

Now I have Dll's that use this interface and have preprocessor defines to worked out if they need to be exported

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
    #define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define MYDLL_API
#endif

class MYDLL_API Derived : public IBase{
public:
    Derived(){}
    ~Derived() override{}
    void someFunction() override {}
}
```

This generates compiler warning "C4275 non - DLL-interface class 'class_1' used as base for DLL-interface class 'class_2'" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-2-c4275?view=msvc-170)

Now if I hadn't added a concrete destructor function on my interface I would not have gotten this error, but I would have leaked Derives' memory like a sieve.

I'm wondering what:

- The correct fix for this problem is
- What could actually go wrong without making the fix

A side note is it is just a warning I could remove with  pragma, but I really don't like doing this especially if I don't 100% understand why it is complaining.

Comment: Just declare it as dllexport/dllimport like any other class that ends up in a DLL.

Comment: Not sure that makes sense. For the dll creating the code this would be __declspec(dllexport), but for a client using the interface this would be __declspec(import), so it needs to change based on what is being compiled, unless I am mistaken; and I assume the answer isn't to add a specific precompiler flag for each interface, because that would be painful

Comment: It's exactly the same kind of ifdef as for Derived, no difference whatsoever. `#ifdef MYBASELIB_EXPORTS` etc. Define `MYBASELIB_EXPORTS` when compiling your static library *and* all the DLLS.

Comment: Yes but imagine I have two dlls who has the define FIRST_DLL and another SECOND_DLL, that both use the interface, but import other interfaces.  I would have to create a interface specific define for every interface used in multiple dlls. (The point of the interface is the dll code behind it can change)

Comment: "I would have to create a interface specific define" I don't see how it is needed. Why are other interfaces relevant? `IBase` is a part of your DLL => needs to be dllexport when building the dll, dllimport when using the dll.  Please post an example where you cannot do that.

Comment: IBase is in a common static library, used by many dlls

Comment: Yes. So? What's the actual problem? Show your code where you are trying to use `#ifdef MYBASELIB_EXPORTS`.

Comment: Extremely hard to show without creating a whole solution, with multiple dlls and interfaces.
Basicly if dll1 exports interface1 and interface2, BUT dll2 exports interface1 and imports interface2, this cannot all be done off the same define.

Comment: Ok if you want to cherry pick what you import and export according t some complex criteria, you need to spell out these criteria somehow. It doesn't matter if these things are interfaces or anything else.

Comment: Yup, that's the basis of the question, I already know how to do compiler defines, as outlined in the post.  However, when it was a pure interface there was no issue. So I'm really asking if there is a way to define an interface without import or export because it literally has no code but a destructor (Or an alternative system)

Comment: "when it was a pure interface there was no issue" Ir was not a part of the DLL, there was nothing to import or export. It was just a bunch of inline or pure functions. (You can dllimport or dllexport an inline function but you don't need to most of the time).

Comment: Makes sense. Given no one else has answered, I assume I am just doing something that is non-standard. Thanks for your time, sorry to be frustrating.